# How to mock 'CdkVirtualScrollViewport' for infinite scrolling in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, karma-jasmine, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

```js
 @ViewChild('scroller')
  scroller!: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.unsub = this.scroller.elementScrolled().pipe(
      map(() => this.scroller.measureScrollOffset('bottom')),
      pairwise(),
      filter(([y1, y2]) => (y2 < y1 && y2 < 140)),
      throttleTime(200)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        (this.maxItems > this.listItems.length) && this.fetchMore();
      });
    })
  }
```

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class="example-viewport" #scroller itemSize="72">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

test case:

```js
  it('should check \'ngAfterViewInit\'', () => {
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    spyOn(virtualScrollViewport, 'elementScrolled').and.callThrough();
    expect(virtualScrollViewport.elementScrolled).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The error trace what I got when mocking

```bash
        Error: Error: cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport requires the "itemSize" property to be set.
            at new CdkVirtualScrollViewport (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/scrolling.js:1264:1)
            at new MockCdkVirtualScrollViewport (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:27773:9)
            at Object.factory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:17371:1)
            at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:17247:42)
            at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:16997:1)
            at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:36383:1)
            at TestBedRender3.inject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:3227:1)
            at Function.inject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:3110:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/components/gridview/gridview.component.spec.ts:112:37)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible implementation of the mock class could be like this:

```
import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class MockCdkVirtualScrollViewport implements CdkVirtualScrollViewport {
  scrolledIndexChange: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
  elementScrolled: Subject<Event> = new Subject<Event>();
  setRenderedRange(): void { }
  getRenderedRange(): any { }
  // add any other properties and methods that are needed for your test
}
```

You can use it in your tests like so:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { MockCdkVirtualScrollViewport } from './mock-cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport';

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  let component: YourComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;
  let virtualScrollViewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // configure the test module with the mock class
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ YourComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: CdkVirtualScrollViewport, useClass: MockCdkVirtualScrollViewport }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    // create an instance of the component and the mock class
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    virtualScrollViewport = TestBed.inject(CdkVirtualScrollViewport);
  });

  it('should do something', () => {
    // use the methods and properties of the mock class in your test
    // for example you can call the `setRenderedRange()` method and check that it works as expected
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please give a detail answer @SeF

Comment: You can use the mock in the beforeEach section by add this in the providers array like so { provide: CdkVirtualScrollViewport, useClass: MockCdkVirtualScrollViewport }

Comment: Hi @SeF
Currently I'm getting the following error

`Error: Error: cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport requires the "itemSize" property to be set.` 

My code:

`
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    spyOn(virtualScrollViewport, 'elementScrolled').and.callThrough();
    expect(virtualScrollViewport.elementScrolled).toHaveBeenCalled();
`

Comment: To fix this error, you will need to set the "itemSize" property on the "cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport" component in your code to the appropriate value.

Comment: `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` is the materal component from `ScrollingModule`. How to set  `itemSize` here. I tried to add `itemSize` as property to `MockCdkVirtualScrollViewport` class. But it also didn't work. Could you please help me with this to fix the error

Comment: The itemSize goes in the html like so <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="50">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

Comment: yeah I've used it in HTML,  but how to include the `itemSize` in test case.... that's where I get error

Comment: In a unit test for a component that uses the <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport> element, you can set the itemSize property by directly manipulating the component's instance.like this: fixture.componentInstance.itemSize = 50; fixture.detectChanges();

Comment: I've added the test case and error what I got for the reference. `itemSize` is not the property of that consuming component. So, unable to do like this `fixture.componentInstance.itemSize = 50;`. I tried to bind the `itemSize` as property binding (`@Input`) inside `MockCdkVirtualScrollViewport` component. Nothing works.... could you please guide me further.

Comment: Found any way to fix?

Comment: You can try to set a static itemSize value in the MockCdkVirtualScrollViewport

Comment: I tried that also `static itemSize = 130;`. But still the same error comes....

Comment: If you create a StackBlitz I can help you to fix this

Comment: Please find the StackBlitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fdcaaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The spec file is empty !

Comment: I've added the test case now. Please have a look at them.

Comment: I think it's related to you angular version you have the angular 7 I suppose

Comment: No... this stackBlitz is using angular version 15... I tried angular 9(in my local)... Angular 15 needed to added `override` to override while mocking... all are same... same error only comes in both the versions

Comment: I see, I let you know if I fix this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251365/discussion-between-sfelli-and-anand-raja).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Initially added `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` to the providers list and with or without a mock it asked for "itemSize" to be set.

In the end removing `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` from the providers list and just adding `ScrollingModule` to the imports list worked. Just the single line.